# Managing transaction in stored procedure with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with Dynamic SQL. Is it possible to include a batch of dynamic SQL inside an explicit transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` depending on the value of `@@ERROR`? 
    Following similar  stored procedure. It is simplified in order to demonstration purpose.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Example] 
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(10)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Deparment] (Name,Location,PhoneNumber) VALUES ('DeparmentName','DeparmentLocation','0112232332')

    SELECT @ID =SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
           ROLLBACK
           RAISERROR ('Error in Inserting Deparment.', 16, 1)
           RETURN
   END
            SET @InsertQuery = '
                                DECLARE @Name varchar(100)

                                SELECT  @Name = Name
                                FROM    dbo.[Deparment]
                                WHERE   DepartmentId= ''' + @ID +'''

                                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee](Name,Age,Salary,DepartmentName)VALUES(''EMPLOYEE NAME'',''25'',''200000'','''+@NAME'')'' 

            EXEC(@InsertQuery)
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
           ROLLBACK
           RAISERROR ('Error in Inserting Employee.', 16, 1)
           RETURN
    END

   COMMIT
END
```

Does outer Transaction scope applies to Dynamic query ?

Comment: Yes, you can exec a dynamic query inside a transaction. 
You can also begin a new transaction within the dynamic query.

Comment: However, unless you are using a very old version of SQL server, you shoudl use try catch blocks instead of the if @@errorr statements. It is very hard to catch all teh errors as you amintain the proc over time using @@error

Comment: Perhaps you have simlifed the code for the example, but tehre is no reason to be using dynamic sql at all with what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The "outer" transaction will apply to everything that is executed. There is no way in SQL Server to *not* execute under the running transaction (which can be annoying of you want to log errors).